# How to update or remove a user from Firebase based on Email Address and Password

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I can create a user with: createUserWithEmailAndPassword

I can sign in a user with: signInWithEmailAndPassword

(Reference: [Firebase Password Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth))

However, I have cases where a user's password has changed since the last time they access my app. I need to either remove the Firebase account and re-create it, or update the password. I don't see anything in the referenced Firebase Docs to support either. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has forgotten their password, they can [requet a password reset email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email).

If you want to delete the account for the user, that can only be done from a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions, through the Admin SDK. See the documentation on [deleting a user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) for that.

Comment: Here is my problem: the UN/PW is created and maintained on the website outside of the app. The user creates a website account, later the same UN/PW is used to create the Firebase account. Then, the user changes their PW on the website. Now, the user cannot login to the app because the PWs don't match. So I would either need to remove and re-create the Firebase account, update its password, or store the original PW permanently for Firebase logins, all without requiring the user to do anything. None of this sounds ideal, but I need to figure out a way to make this work on my deployed app.

Comment: I think I probably need to clear out all the Firebase accounts, establish a dedicated, secondary Firebase password for each user (which never changes), and use that for automatic logins to Firebase.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by creating the user on the website, but it sounds like you're storing the same information in two places - which is bound to lead to this type of problem. I highly recommend **only** storing the user credentials in one place (typically Firebase), and deriving all functionality from that.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase does support [password resets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email) via email if that is what you are looking for.

Also you can delete users, but if you cant accesss the **current user** object as you dont have the signin information, you will need to use the Admin SDK to [manage the users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).